# How do I boot windows XP in virtual box into repair mode?

Tags: boot, windows-xp, virtualbox, operating-systems

As the question states, I am attempting to boot Windows XP into repair mode using virtual box, I've seen the repair mode option in newer Windows versions but all I could manage in XP is booting in safe mode. The host system is a Linux OS(Manjaro).

Comment: Make sure the CD in your host system is connected to the Virtual Machine.  Start the XP Guest with the CD and use the Repair Function.

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP did not have a built-in repair environment. (It had none of the current "servicing stack" improvements that were introduced with Vista – there was no DISM yet, the installer was .cab-based.)

The closest thing available is the "Repair installation" option in the Windows *install CD* – after the initial "To install, press ENTER" screen, you can select an existing Windows folder and have the installer try to repair it.

(After this is done, the system will *probably* be at whatever version the CD contains, so you will most likely need to re-install every single update.)

However, if you can get into Safe Mode, you can instead try rolling back to an earlier "System Restore Point" snapshot (which is available through Start > Accessories > System Tools), which will roll back OS changes while preserving your file changes.

Comment: DISM couldn't repair Windows 7 either, it could be use to image your system, but Windows 7 DISM was severely limited compared to Windows 8's version